# Saucelab - webdriverio : sessionID for sauce dashboard

Tags: saucelabs, webdriver-io

I am trying out wdio and saucelabs. I see way to https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Setting+Up+Reporting+between+Sauce+Labs+and+Jenkins configure report by outputting the sessionID

I am not able to figure out how I can do using webdriverio javascript method.

can you point to some example if this is possible with javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

WebdriverIO comes with a Sauce service that automatically integrates this for you: http://webdriver.io/guide/services/sauce.html

If you're interested in more details, [I wrote a blog post about a similar method I used for integrating Jenkins and Browserstack](http://blog.kevinlamping.com/better-browserstack-builds-in-webdriverio/).